# Dataframe to lists in alphabetical order - Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a requirement to create lists from a dataframe.
For eg: I have a dataframe "df" containing a column called "names" and it has 30 random names.

I want to create separate lists in alphabetical order like names starting from a to d will go to list1, e to g will go to list2 and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How many lists do you want the names split into?

Comment: I will use math.ceil(len(df)/4) for this

Comment: I don't understand the relation between your formula and the separated lists? If you have only names begin by A, you have only one list at the end, right?

Comment: If suppose my dataframe has 30 random names, number of lists to be created is math.ceil(len(df)/4)=8 lists. So each list should contain 4 names. list1 will contain first 4 df items,list2 will contain next 4 df items and so on till list8

Answer (score 0):

This one does 4 lists total

```
import pandas as pd
import math
df = pd.DataFrame({"names": ['Jon', 'Bill', 'Maria', 'Jenny', 'Jack', 'sam', 'john']})
t = df['names'].values.tolist()
t = sorted(t)
split = [[], [], [], []]
for i, name in enumerate(t):
    var = math.floor(i * 4 / len(t))
    split[var].append(name)
>>> print(split)
>>> [['Bill', 'Jack'], ['Jenny', 'Jon'], ['Maria', 'john'], ['sam']]
```

Comment: This will work but I cannot decide every time it will be 4 lists. So i cannot give split=4 empty lists. I want that to be calculated

Comment: How is the number of lists decided?

Comment: we can use math.ceil(len(df)/4) which means 4 values in a list

Comment: Got it, quick fix then

Comment: Sorry didn't understand

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 0):

This one does 4 names per list

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"names": ['Jon', 'Bill', 'Maria', 'Jenny', 'Jack', 'sam', 'john']})
t = sorted(df['names'].values.tolist())
split = []
for i in range(0, int(len(t) // 4) + 1):
    split.append([])
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    print(i // 4)
    split[int(i // 4)].append(t[i])
>>> print(split)
[['Bill', 'Jack', 'Jenny', 'Jon'], ['Maria', 'john', 'sam']]
```